# How do I modify this PostgreSQL table?

Tags: postgresql, postfix-mta, phppgadmin

I'm using PostgreSQL in my SBC, running Parabola (Arch and ALARM based). I was reading [this tutorial](https://thejimmyg.github.io/goodingredients/recipe/articles/email3/postfix-gateway.html) so I can use PostgreSQL databases and make Postfix work with them. However, in [this step](https://thejimmyg.github.io/goodingredients/recipe/articles/email3/postfix-gateway.html#the-domain-table) I have to fill up some info in the tables I've created, right? How do I do that? Would be better if I can use pgAdmin3 or phpPgAdmin for this, but if I **have** to do in CLI, there's no problem.

Thanks.

**EDIT**: I'm a complete noob with PostgreSQL. I'm trying to learn about it, so if you need more info please tell me how to get it.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please provides more details if you want help. Precice question, [MCVE] lead to useful answers

Comment: If the table already exists consider `ALTER TABLE` statement, see [reference](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altertable.html)

Comment: Do I have to add a row maybe?

Comment: I dont know your question is still unclear, vague... Maybe it is, may be not. Please read a bit more about how to [ask a question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Short example, and you can run these from pgadmin3 etc as well as the command line.

```
create table tester (a int, b text);
insert into tester select generate_series(1,1000),'sometext';
select * from tester;
```

If you need random text, the easy way is to load something like a Shakespeare novel, and use random and substring to grab random sections from that one row in that one table.